# How can I deleting the content of a file without deleting it self?

Tags: java, file

I want to clear the content of a file witch have a specific extension file.tctl, i don't want to change any thing about the file neither deleting it. The file is generated from a specific model checker so that i have just to delete the content and write my own. I tried to print an empty string like that:

`PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file.tctl);
writer.print("");
writer.close();`

but the file doesn't work any more. So if there's another method to clear the content of the file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call your write() method like this:

```
.write((new String()).getBytes());
```

This will make your file empty. If that doesn't works, try with this:

```
FileOutputStream erasor = new FileOutputStream("filename.ext");
erasor.write((new String()).toByteArray());
erasor.close();
```

Or just try to overwrite the file

```
//open file in override mode
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("filename.ext");
//now anything that we write here will remove the old one so just write space ("") here
```

Comment: yep it was helpful :D

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't compile: the second is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the print altogether from your code. You've already truncated the file with the new FileOutputStream/PrintWriter/ whatever you use to open it. No I/O or truncate() necessary. Don't use append mode.

Comment: can you please explain more i can't understand what you mean exactly

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way I guess

```
new RandomAccessFile("filename.ext", "rw").setLength(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a FileOutputStream and then you have the truncate() method:

```
File f = new File("path-of-the-file.here");
FileChannel channel = new FileOutputStream(f, true).getChannel();
channel.truncate(0);
channel.close();
```

Comment: but if I use new File, the file will be deleted and new file, with the same name, will be created. I want to keep the same file

Comment: No, new File does not create a new file in the directory, it only creates a "file representation" in java.

Comment: Removing append mode and the truncation works just as well: you don't 'have' to do it this way.